# Jxl CellType is overwritten by setCellFormat when document is opened

Tags: format, jxl

I use Jxl (v2.6.10) library for generating xls documents. I want to have formatted DateTime cells.
All works well if using no format for cells:

```
WritableCell wc = new jxl.write.DateTime(5, 5, new java.util.Date()); 
sheet.addCell(wc);
```

In the document the cell has Date format and is displayed as "8/16/2012". 
But when I add:

```
WritableCell wc = new jxl.write.DateTime(5, 5, new java.util.Date()); 
wc.setCellFormat(new WritableCellFormat());
sheet.addCell(wc);
```

Then only a "41137.4459694444" is displayed (I used LibreOffice, but it's same with Google docs). When I manually change Cell formatting in the spreadsheet then the number is turned to 8/16/2012 as expected.

I thought that setCellFormat overwrites wc.getCellType() but that is not true:

```
jxl.write.DateTime wc = new jxl.write.DateTime(5, 5, new java.util.Date());
System.out.println(wc.getType());
wc.setCellFormat(new WritableCellFormat());
System.out.println(wc.getType());
wc.setDate(new java.util.Date());
System.out.println(wc.getType());
```

yields:

```
Date
Date
Date
```

I wish to know what is happening here because now I am confused.